# java: Android: use case: when to use map view and when to redirect to maps applications?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I have an application and I would be showing driving directions to a particular set of places depending on the place a user chooses. When should you have an API key and display maps and when should you use inbuilt or other maps installed. Whatsapp for instance redirects to other apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your use case or any general use case this can be done,

Quoting from the Google documentations:

> Your application needs an API key to access the Google Maps servers

So, whenever you need to display a map inside your App you will need an API key,this can serve you for displaying markers/places on your App, showing route between two places or calculating the distance between them,

On the other hand, if you want to provide directions you will need to use to Google Maps App and redirect to it.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to display direction then use map app whereas if you want to display location on map then use MapView.